# Deploy on heroku without keeping gradlew file

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, heroku

I am building a demo Spring Boot application with Gradle and using Heroku to host the app. I have preinstalled Gradle 4.8 so I am not keeping `gradlew` file in the project directory, and the app is running fine on local but when I deploying it on heroku using `git push heroku master`. The logs showing below warning:

```
remote: -----> Installing Gradle Wrapper...
remote:        WARNING: Your application does not have it's own gradlew file.
remote:        We'll install one for you, but this is a deprecated feature and
remote:        in the future may not be supported.
remote: -----> Building Gradle app...
remote: -----> executing ./gradlew build -x test
```

and the build fails after showing Gradle version error:

```
remote:        * What went wrong:
remote:        A problem occurred evaluating root project 'xxx'.
remote:        > Spring Boot plugin requires Gradle 4.0 or later. The current version is Gradle 2.0
```

Means it using default `gradle` file and which installing 2.0 to deploy app.

Now my query is, how can I force Heroku deploy process to use preinstalled Gradle version without keeping `gradlew` in project dir and not to install it's default deprecated `gradlew`?

Answer (score 0):

The Heroku Gradle buildpack does not support using Gradle version > 2.x without a `gradlew` file. This is inline with the [official Gradle recommendation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html).

However, you can fork the [Heroku Gradle buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-gradle) and edit the [default wrapper, which installs Gradle](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-gradle/tree/master/opt/wrapper). Then you can set your fork as a custom buildpack on your Heroku app.